# back button not appearing nested view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am navigating between two views, from `app.list` to `app.single` using `$state.go('app.single')`

When I reach the `app.single` there is no back button! Only the hamburger button, what am I doing wrong? Here are my routes...

```
.state('app.list', {
    url: '/list',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
            controller: 'listCtrl'
        }
    }
})


.state('app.single', {
    url: '/list/item',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/single.html',
            controller: 'singleCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: can you show more code? What does your ionicConfig look like? Are you changing ionicHistory for any reason?